# How to get object's information and push to GUI with Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a Java delivery project with a GUI that I want to implement.

I have 3 functionalities:
Create,
Delete, and
Edit

My GUI basically looks like this:

[image: delivery_GUI]

My Questions are: When I'm entering the Data and using the button Create: How I can create the object and push those informations to my Main method below:

```
Truck cyberTruck = new Truck(1,"1339TRCK",1000, 100, 2267, 20);
```

My Truck class looks like this:

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private int numberOfTrailers;

public Truck(int numberOfTrailers, String registrationNumber, double volume, float averageSpeed, float maxWeight, int length){
        super(registrationNumber, volume, averageSpeed, maxWeight, length);
        this.numberOfTrailers = numberOfTrailers;
    }
```

So, the parameters are numberOfTrailers, registirationNumber, volume, averageSpeed, maxWeight and length.

**I would like to know how I will push all of those inputs into the main and create new object with my GUI.
Also when I will create the Truck, it should display on the JList on the left side, by selecting the Truck from JList I should be able to Delete it also. Last step is to be able to see all the informations when I click on the name of the Truck from JList and display all properties to the JTextField.**

Comment: *"My Questions are:"* 1) SO is a Q&A site that works best if each thread is focused on one question only, and has a title that describes that question. 2) While the title *is* effectively a single question, it needs a '?' at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this contains a lot of questions. I'll try with this approach:

First, you need an ActionListener for the "Create" button
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Second, you need to read the values from the JTExtField
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

With the values, you can create a "Truck" object an store it in a list that you can pass to the JList
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)